# is shared storage safe in Postgres if all servers are read-only?

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering

Description of shared storage in Postgres: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Shared_Storage

Related question: https://serverfault.com/a/620315/137464

Both of these make it clear that it's not safe to have one write instance and many readers.  What about if **all** instances are read-only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [answer you linked to](https://serverfault.com/a/620315/137464), Craig says:

> It's possibly practical to do it **with minor changes to PostgreSQL(** if all the servers are read-only, but I haven't investigated it as it's a pretty uninteresting use-case.

(emphasis mine).

The problem is, there is no way to start a PostgreSQL server and tell it "you are only allowed to look at this data directory, you are not allowed to write anything at all". Even a PostgreSQL server operating as a "hot standby" takes the liberty of writing arbitrary files inside its data directory (e.g. postmaster.pid, temporary files used for on-disk sorts, [rewriting hint bits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-ADMIN), and so on). If two or more servers *were* coaxed into operating in hot standby mode against the same data directory, chaos could ensue.

There is simply no "look but don't touch" mode for a Postgres server, so the answer to:

> What about if all [Postgres server instances operating against the same shared data directory] are read-only?

is: not possible today without changing Postgres to implement a true read-only mode.